# dd command finished very quickly but does not transfer data

Tags: hard-drive, command-line, disk-utility, partition

I'm trying to restore a Windows installer image to an external hard drive. To do this, I decided to use the command line because Disk Utility never bloody works.

To identify the disk, I used `diskutil list` which generated the following output:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            499.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Macintosh HD           +499.0 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 604D1BA8-46A5-41AD-8D62-7898021A4D16
                                 Unencrypted

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS 500G Storage            489.8 GB   disk3s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data WINDOWS                 9.9 GB     disk3s3
```

I identified the disk I want to use as `disk3s3`, a 10GB MS-FAT partition on the external hard drive. I then unmounted it with `sudo diskutil unmount /dev/disk3s3`. Now, to restore an ISO image to this partition, I use the following command:

`$ sudo dd if=~/Desktop/Windows.iso of=~/dev/disk3s3 bs=1m`

I don't get any errors upon running the command initially but after only a few seconds it finishes with this output:

```
3165+1 records in
3165+1 records out
3319764992 bytes transferred in 10.191605 secs (325735246 bytes/sec)
```

However much I wished this output was correct, it is not. No data whatsoever was transferred to the drive. How is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is OK except that you shouldn't use ~ in dd commands (it's not forbidden but error-prone) and of=~/dev/disk3s3 is a file in your /Users/yourusername/dev folder (which probably wasn't intended but explains the 326 MB/s) instead of the real destination */dev/disk3s3*.

So better enter:

```
sudo dd if=~/Desktop/Windows.iso of=/dev/disk3s3 bs=1m
```

or much better

```
sudo dd if=/Users/yourusername/Desktop/Windows.iso of=/dev/disk3s3 bs=1m
```

Comment: Or use: `sudo dd if=$HOME/Desktop/Windows.iso ...`

Comment: Ahh stupid typo... `~/dev/disk3s3` isn't even a thing haha!

Comment: @RoemerBakker If you have a dev folder (visible or invisible) in your user folder the command **will** create the file disk3s3. If you **don't** have a dev folder, no file will be created and you get an error: `... No such file or directory`. So check your $HOME/dev and delete the file disk3s3... ;-)